# Link boxes won't touch bottom of header

Tags: html, css

Right now I am trying to get the bottom of the boxes with links in them to touch the bottom of the header but can't get it to do that. I tried removing as much padding as possible I have tried making the boxes position absolute and I just can't do it. Here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Excercise 2 CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />

</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
      <img src="img.png" id="top_image" alt="top_image" />
      <div class="link_container">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </div>
      <div class="link_container">
        <a href="#">Locations</a>
      </div>
      <div class="link_container">
        <a href="#">New Account</a>
      </div>
      <div class="link_container">
        <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </div>

     </div>
    <div class="content">






    </div>
    <div class="footer">
            <p><b><i>Copyright 2011 Hometown Bank, Inc.</i></b>
            <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
            <a href="#">Legal</a></p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the css

```
html { height: 100%; width: 100%;  smin-height: 1000px;  }
        body { height: 90%; width: 90%; min-width: 1135px; min-height: 570px; margin:0px; margin-left:5%; margin-top: 2%; 
                box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 5px  #999999; margin-bottom:5%; background-color: #FFFFFF;
              }

        .header 
         { 

            height: 10%;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #DAFFFF;
            spadding-top: 1%;
            min-height: 100px;
         }



        .content 
        { 
            height:75%;
            width: 100%;
            min-height:390px;;

            background-color:#DAFFAA;
        }

        .text_area  
        { 

            height: 135px; width:700px;  position:relative; 
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:18px; 
            padding: 15px 20px 15px 10px;
            margin-bottom:25px; background-color:#00EEFF;

        }

        .news_header 
        { 
            width:250px; background-color:#00CCCC; height: 30px;
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:20px;
            padding-top:5px;
        }
        .news_box
        {
            height:170px; width:250px; background-color: #00EEFF;
            float:right;  display:inline;

        }

        .footer
        {
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            height: 5%;
            width: 100%;
            background-color:#00BBBB;
            min-height:25px;
            margin: 0px;

        }
        .link_container
        {
           display:inline-block;
           height:50%;
           width:10%;
           background-color:#FF0;

        }
.header img { margin-left:2%; width:10%; height: 75px;}
```

If there is any more info you need please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your combination of `height:10%` and `min-height:100px` seems to be causing it.  Removing it makes your links line up at the bottom of the header div.

http://jsfiddle.net/tomprogramming/namH7/1/

Comment: How do I make the link boxes taller?

Comment: either specify an exact height for your header (http://jsfiddle.net/tomprogramming/namH7/2/), since percentage heights only work if the parent has a defined height, or specify an exact height for the boxes themselves (http://jsfiddle.net/tomprogramming/namH7/3/)

Comment: It was a combination of your advise and users advice that fixed but since most of yours was the one that helped i'll accept yours.

Answer (score 1):

Change the height on your link container to 100% so the divs fill their containers.

```
    .link_container
    {
       display:inline-block;
       height:100%;
       width:10%;
       background-color:#FF0;

    }
```

Then add vertical-align style to the image to position the divs relative to the image.

```
<img src="img.png" id="top_image" alt="top_image" style="vertical-align:top;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to move your yellow link boxes down you can either do it with margin-top or position: relative;

```
    .link_container
    {
       margin-top: 50px;
       or
       position: relative;
       top: 50px;

    }
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that there was 50px down to the bottom of your header html tag.